# How do I return the XPath of a tag using XUL?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I would like to select the XPath of a tag and the content of the tag, something similar to what [Evernote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evernote) is doing. However, I cannot find any examples. How could this be achieved?

Comment: Are you aware that there is no "the XPath of a tag"? You could select the same tag by many different XPath expressions, which one do you want? I guess that you want to go by the element's position in the document, similarly to what [Remove It Permanently](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/remove-it-permanently/) is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research we found this:

```
function createXPathFromElement(elm) {
        var allNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('*'); 
        for (segs = []; elm && elm.nodeType == 1; elm = elm.parentNode) 
        {
            if (elm.hasAttribute('id')) { 
                var uniqueIdCount = 0; 
                for (var n=0;n < allNodes.length;n++) { 
                    if (allNodes[n].hasAttribute('id') && allNodes[n].id == elm.id) uniqueIdCount++; 
                    if (uniqueIdCount > 1) break; 
                }; 
                if ( uniqueIdCount == 1) { 
                    segs.unshift('id("' + elm.getAttribute('id') + '")'); 
                    return segs.join('/'); 
                } else { 
                    segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[@id="' + elm.getAttribute('id') + '"]'); 
                } 
            } else if (elm.hasAttribute('class')) { 
                segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[@class="' + elm.getAttribute('class') + '"]'); 
            } else { 
                for (i = 1, sib = elm.previousSibling; sib; sib = sib.previousSibling) { 
                    if (sib.localName == elm.localName)  i++;
                }; 
                segs.unshift(elm.localName.toLowerCase() + '[' + i + ']'); 
            }; 
        };
        return segs.length ? '/' + segs.join('/') : null; 
    }

    function lookupElementByXPath(path) {
        var evaluator = new XPathEvaluator(); 
        var result = evaluator.evaluate(path, document.documentElement, null,XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null); 
        return  result.singleNodeValue; 
    }
```